# I cannot call another screen when I click on the image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two images to simulate the click on the button, but I want is when clicking the image and change call another screen. And the process does not happen because the application is stopping

```
<StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Image Source="botaocadastrolivre.png">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>




void  OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            tapCount++;
            var imageSender = (Image)sender;
            // watch the monkey go from color to black&white!
            if (tapCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                imageSender.Source = "botaocadastrolivre.png";
            }
            else
            {
                imageSender.Source = "botaocadastroPresed.png";
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Nova());
            }
           // Task.Delay(100)
           //Navigation.PushAsync(new Nova());
        }
```

Comment: is it unresponsive? Have you tried async?

Comment: My guess would be that something goes wrong on Nova page. Put the breakpoint in the constructor of Nova page and see if its being hit.

Comment: Already tried yes, but in the same the application stop. @Code

Comment: @Woj I'm taking an exception 
Unhandled Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: @amarotati - Use `PushModelAsync` instead of `PushAsync`.

Comment: See the answer below then. :) Gerald explained it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `App.xaml.cs` file, find the line that says something like:

```
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

and change it into:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

This will wrap your page into a navigation page and then the `Navigation` object will know how to navigate from one page to the other.

It might be wise to read up on navigation concepts in Xamarin.Forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/